# How to format string the ffmpeg arguments to pass the arguments to a textBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, ffmpeg

I created this form :

[image: arguments]

I want to use the variable ffmpegArguments to pass the arguments from the textBox to the ffmpeg class arguments.  the problem is that in the ffmpeg class i'm using the variables :

FileName and Framerate so how can i format the input from the textBox to the ffmpeg arguments with the FileName and Framerate variables ?

In the ffmpeg class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Capture_Screen
{
    internal class FFmpeg_Capture
    {
        public string workingDirectory;
        public string outputDirectory;
        public string ffmpegArguments;

        private Process process;

        public FFmpeg_Capture()
        {
            
        }

        public void Start(string FileName, int Framerate)
        {
            process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = outputDirectory; // Change the directory where ffmpeg.exe is.  
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory; // The output directory  
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-y -f gdigrab -framerate " + Framerate +
                " -i desktop -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p " + FileName;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; //Redirect stdin
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            byte[] qKey = Encoding.GetEncoding("gbk").GetBytes("q"); //Get encoding of 'q' key
            process.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(qKey, 0, 1); //Write 'q' key to stdin of FFmpeg sub-processs
            process.StandardInput.BaseStream.Flush(); //Flush stdin (just in case).
            process.Close();
            process.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you provide the list of arguments user can provide in a tabular data (gird options) so whichever is filled in you can construct the list of arguments and pass it to your processor, if you provide free text it would be a problem for both sides

Comment: Add a text box or other control for each separate argument and then build the them. Or pass them as separate pieces. Otherwise put some markers. `a/fileName:value1 a/framerate:value2`. split by `a/` and the left part of `left:right` is name, right-value.